# Github Page not working with hexo?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, hexo

I am recently developing my personal blog using Hexo framework but I have problem pushing my web content to Github Page Service to host my web application. I buy a domain name for my website. I am following the Hexo deployment instruction [here](https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html) but it is not working. Here is the code of deployment part of my configure_yml file. Thanks for your help!

```
# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/ZhackerZ/ZhackerZ.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already pointed your DNS to your github page ([documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/)), you have to wait for DNS replication.

> Your DNS changes can take over a full day to update and the wait varies among DNS and hosting providers.

For now your domain is still pointing to goddady.

```
$: dig www.zhackerz.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.zhackerz.com.   3371    IN  CNAME   zhackerz.com.
zhackerz.com.       371 IN  A   50.63.202.39

$: dig zhackerz.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
zhackerz.com.       349 IN  A   50.63.202.39
```

Comment: So All I need is waiting for the DNS changes happens?

Comment: Yes. If you've made the DNS change, it will propagate within a day or two max.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to made the DNS change. I still have a small problem, goDaddy asks me to choose the customer nameServer. What should I input? It has two required fields. I try to use command "dig ZhackerZ.github.io" but which value should I pick?

Comment: You can search "godaddy github pages" for lore info on this.